# jetty BadMessage: 400 No Host for HttpChannelOverHttp

Tags: http, jetty, apache-camel, dropwizard

I have seen previous posts about Jetty BadMessage: 400 No Host for HttpChannelOverHttp and I can confirm that I am able to repeat the problem.

I have a Jetty route in Camel Blueprint, which creates another request and forwards on to a Dropwizard service via Camel HTTP.

```
.process(new Processor() {
//Creates Object for request
}

.marshal(jsonFormat)
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(serviceEndpoint))
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethod.POST))
.to(userviceEndpoint)
```

When this request executes, I see the following error on Dropwizard

```
WARN  [2014-11-12 23:15:35,333] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: BadMessage: 400 No Host for HttpChannelOverHttp@3aa99dd2{r=0,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

This happens constantly, and this problem does not occur when I send a request to the DW service using SOAP-UI (using the serviceEndpoint URL).

Please if anyone has solved this problem, I would like to know how. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture your network traffic, and post the HTTP request headers you are sending to Jetty.

Odds are that your HTTP client is not sending the `Host:` header (which is required on HTTP/1.1)

Comment: Thank you. The camel-http component does not send the Host header for some reason. I switched to the camel-http4 and this has fixed this. On to more problems :-). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was setting header with `null` value. After removing header having `null` value from request solved the issue.

Jetty Version: 9.3.8

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was making a request with incorrectly formatted headers. So instead of having the header as "X_S_ID: ABC" I had "X_S_ID: ["X_S_ID":BLAH]". So the error sometimes may not literally mean you need to pass a Host header.

Fixing the headers fixed this. Print the exact request you are making and make sure all headers are correctly formatted.